# Lync chat 2010 notifications

Tags: c#, lync-server-2010

I'm looking for direction on if it's possible to have a win form in the background watch a group chat channel and provide notification popup when a string is typed in chat.

I've only found resources for Lync chat.

Nothing on how to establish a connection to a channel and read the chat as people talk.

Any help is appreciated.